# Where is the Frameworks folder for a test target?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I have created a local copy of the Nimble test framework and I am attempting to add it to the test target of a default, empty, Xcode project. I have added the 'Copy Files', build phase for Nimble.framework in the test target. The framework now magically appears in my project navigator.
[image]

After adding Nimble.framework to 'Link Binary With Libraries' I get the linking error; Nimble.framework not found.
[image]

A spotlight search of my machine only finds Nimble.framework in the git directories where I created it. **Where are the Framework directories that Xcode uses?**

My `Runpath Search Paths` build variable has `@executable_path/../Frameworks` and `@loader_path/../Frameworks`. I have added `@loader_path/Frameworks` to these to be safe but my information sources are probably dated.

Yes, I have clean built and deleted entirely the DerivedData folder many times already trying to figure this out.